# A problem related to three outputs of the majority function for nine rotations of three bitstrings

Tags: complexity

Let $r(b,t)$ denote the bitstring $b$ rotated to the left by $t$ bits: for example, $$r(00110101,5)=10100110.$$

Let $m(b_1,b_2,b_3)$ denote the [majority function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Majority_function): for example, $$m(10010111,00101110,10100000)=10100110.$$

Consider the following game. Player A picks three arbitrary $n$-bit strings $(S_1,S_2,S_3)$ and nine arbitrary integers $(k_1,k_2,\ldots,k_9)$ less than $n.$ Then Player A computes

$$\begin{array}{l}
X_1 = m(r(S_1,k_1), r(S_2,k_2), r(S_3,k_3)),\\
X_2 = m(r(S_1,k_4), r(S_2,k_5), r(S_3,k_6)),\\
X_3 = m(r(S_1,k_7), r(S_2,k_8), r(S_3,k_9)),
\end{array}$$

then reveals $X_1$, $X_2$ and $X_3$ to Player B (we can assume that $X_1 \neq X_2, X_1 \neq X_3, X_2 \neq X_3.$)

Given $X_1$, $X_2$ and $X_3$, how hard is it (in the *average* case) for the Player B to find three arbitrary $n$-bit strings $(Y_1,Y_2,Y_3)$ and nine arbitrary integers $(v_1,v_2,\ldots,v_9)$ such that $$\begin{array}{l}
X_1 = m(r(Y_1,v_1), r(Y_2,v_2), r(Y_3,v_3)),\\
X_2 = m(r(Y_1,v_4), r(Y_2,v_5), r(Y_3,v_6)),\\
X_3 = m(r(Y_1,v_7), r(Y_2,v_8), r(Y_3,v_9))?
\end{array}$$

Comment: Doesn't look that difficult; one approach would be to assign $v_1=v_2=v_3=0$, nonzero random values for the others, and then do backtracking at a bit level (e.g. look at the four possible bit settings of bit 0 of $X_0$, and follow the implications.  My guess is that most branches relatively quickly run into contradictions, and if so, you either find a solution or not (and if not, try other random settings for $v_4$ et al).  I haven't actually tried it, though...